# Custom CSS in Widget editor (Gutenberg) gets stripped out

Tags: css, widgets, block-editor

As of WP 5.8.1 (or 5.8.0) the Gutenberg Editor gets to be default even for Widgets.

So I've started to create some Widgets with Gutenberg blocks. My issue is that if I add custom CSS to the blocks (through the block editor's custom css tab, wrapped in the `selector {...}` statement), it gets stripped out when the page is rendered.

[image]

Question: is this

- a bug
- an intended behaviour
- or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: How are you adding CSS to the blocks?

Comment: @JacobPeattie through the block editor options -> custom css tab and with the `selector {...}` wrapper. See my edit in the question.

Comment: That is not a standard WordPress feature. Is that from a plugin? Or perhaps it's a feature of specific blocks your using? Either way, you would need to ask the author of that feature.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hmmm... I wasn't aware of that, but it looks like the theme I'm using incorporates the [Blocks CSS Editor Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blocks-css/) ... This resolves my question (but not my problem). - I'd accept that as an answer if you want to wirte it, otherwise I'll just delete the question and rethink everything. Thank you.